# RNGCryptoServiceProvider to get a random 256 bit integer in c#

Tags: c#, random, integer, numbers

I am trying to generate a 256 bit integer in c# using RNGCryptoServiceProvider. My code is:

```
// 256 bits random number
byte[] random = new Byte[32];
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
rng.GetBytes(random);            Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToUInt64(random,0));
return BitConverter.ToUInt64(random,0);
```

However, the output are integers like 6958393268188363168, which is not 77 digits long. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: "RNGCryptoServiceProvider is obsolete. To generate a random number, use one of the RandomNumberGenerator static methods instead." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?view=net-6.0

Comment: Uint64 is, as the name suggests, 64-bit, not 256-bit. You would probably need `BigInteger`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57045431/3181933

Comment: You are returning 64 bits not 256.  Either you have to use BigInteger or return 32 bytes.  BitConverter does not make any sense.